# Random Numbers printed while trying to run Hello World Program in MPI on two computers

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I am trying basic Hello_World program in MPI but it is printing random numbers which shouldn't be printing at all(I am not printing any numbers in the program).

I am following this tutorial:
http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/

My mpirun command is as followed:
mpirun -np 2 -host my.ip.add,username@other.ip.add ./a.out

The two computers are connected over same wifi and have same version of MPI installed. The code is as followed:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    // Print off a hello world message
    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d"
           " out of %d processors\n",
           processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

**EDIT**

I ran following mpirun command and the output is as followed:

```
Command : mpirun -np 1 -host my.ip.add, uname@other.ip.add ./a.out
Output: Hello world from processor pranav, rank 0 out of 1 processors
```

Changing the number of processes to 2, the following random output as mentioned above is seen:

```
Command: mpirun -np 2 -host my.ip.add, uname@other.ip.add ./a.out
Output: 199931 199931
        1 2 1
        2 3 1
        3 4 1
        4 5 1
        5 6 1
        6 7 1 
        7 8 1
        8 9 1 
        9 10 1 ...
```

The numbers go in an infinite loop with pattern as seen above. Also i would like to note that in first output, there is no output from process of the other computer.

Comment: Please post the output of your program. What happens if you only run on one node ? Note you should either `return 0;` or `exit(0);` after `MPI_Finalize();`

Comment: See edit of the current post for output.

Comment: Make sure `a.out` is the same on both hosts. Are you running the program from a shared directory?

Comment: your output does not make any sense ... I do not think a whitespace is allowed before `uname@other.ip.add`. I suggest you try `mpirun -np 1 -host my.ip.add,uname@other.ip.add md5sum ./a.out` and `mpirun -np 2 -host my.ip.add,uname@other.ip.add md5sum ./a.out` to make sure you are running the same binary in both cases.